Sub-2x2 matrix product within 4-dimensional tensor, along given axis
I have a ndarray structure with 4 dimensions: (K,N,2,2). You can imagine this as K different stacks, containing each of them N matrices of dimension 2x2.
For each stack, I'm trying to compute the matrix product of its N matrices (without For loop). So in the end, I should have K matrices of dimensions 2x2 (the product of N 2x2 matrices remains a 2x2 matrix).
If my array was of dimensions (N,2,2), this is quite straightforward to perform matrix product along the 1st axis with the following function:
A_total = np.linalg.multi_dot(A)  # A being a (N,2,2) array

But with a (K,N,2,2) structure, I don't manage to perform the same operation along the 2nd axis, while ignoring the 1st axis.
Would you have any suggestion on this? I have tried with np.einsum() and np.tensordot() but don't quite understand how to correctly use those functions.

np.linalg.multi_dot(np.random.random((2, 2, 5))) throws a ValueError: shapes (2,5) and (2,5) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0). Please [edit] your question to include an example input and output

for np.linalg.multi_dot, the dims of A should be (N, 2, 2) instead of (2, 2, N). This has the desired result: np.linalg.multi_dot(np.random.random((5, 2, 2)))

multi_dot does not avoid python level loops.  It still chains dots, dot(A, dot(B,C)) etc Only if the arrays vary in size, it picks an optimal order.  But yours are all (2,2).  Provide a small looped or chained version so we are sure what you want.

Roughly what's the size of K compared to N?

I suspect you'll have to either do K multidot, or chain matmul N-1 times..  Practice with something small to see which is easier and faster.

To add to the dilemma, I would add that chaining matmul could be done in O(log(N)) python operation. If you have 2×8 2×2 matrices [[A,B,C,D, E,F,G,H], [I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P]] (each A,B,C being a 2×2 matrix; so K=2, N=8), you could compute [[AB, CD, EF, GH], [IJ, KL, MN, OP]], then [[ABCD, EFGH], [IJKL, MNOP]] then your wanted [ABCDEFGH, IJKLMNOP] with 3 matrix multiplication (of course it doesn't change the overall complexity: each of those operations cost, on average O(KN/log(N)), so that is still O(KN) matrix multiplications. But only 3 in pure python iteration.

But it this case, since K is only 2, it may be more efficient to still use multidot. (Not sure, because of what @hpaulj said: multidot just chain dot. I guess, only experiments could say for which ratio K/N, or which ratio K/log(N), one of the approach is the best)

Let's try the 2 obvious alternatives for small K=3, N=5
In [95]: A = np.random.rand(3,5,2,2)

First iterate on K, the stack:
In [96]: res = np.array([np.linalg.multi_dot(A[i,...]) for i in range(A.shape[0])])

In [97]: res.shape
Out[97]: (3, 2, 2)

Now chain on N:
In [98]: res1=A[:,0,:,:].copy()
    ...: for j in range(1,A.shape[1]):
    ...:     res1 = res1@A[:,j,:,:]
    ...:     

They match:
In [99]: np.allclose(res, res1)
Out[99]: True

Timings for the iterative chaining are much better:
In [100]: timeit res = np.array([np.linalg.multi_dot(A[i,...]) for i in range(A.shape[0])])
329 µs ± 1.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [101]: %%timeit 
     ...: res1=A[:,0,:,:].copy()
     ...: for j in range(1,A.shape[1]):
     ...:     res1 = res1@A[:,j,:,:]
     ...:     
33.7 µs ± 767 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

So unless the K/N ratio is very different, I'd stick with the repeated matmul.  matmul is linear on the lead dimensions (of 3+), but that iteration is in compiled code.
much bigger N
In [102]: A = np.random.rand(3,50,2,2)

In [103]: timeit res = np.array([np.linalg.multi_dot(A[i,...]) for i in range(A.shape[0])])
98.1 ms ± 197 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [104]: %%timeit 
     ...: res1=A[:,0,:,:].copy()
     ...: for j in range(1,A.shape[1]):
     ...:     res1 = res1@A[:,j,:,:]
     ...:     
339 µs ± 722 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

