Matrix multiplixation over axis in numpy
Suppose I have an array X of shape (B, N, N, 3, 3). I want to vectorise the operation
X[:,0,...] @ X[:,1,...] ... @ X[:,N-1,...]
How can I vectorise this in numpy? I don't want to use for loops.
I tried using einsum, but it didn't work for me, it ended up summing the matrices.
EDIT: I'm using Jax, if it makes any difference here

What you've written is best.  There isn't a 'vectorized' version.  There is a multi_dot, but it still iterates (recursively).  This was discussed in more depth in a recent SO.

Repeated @/matmul (or einsum) is the only option.  multi_dot requires a sequence of 2d arrays.  You have a sequence of 4d arrays, all the same shape.

I explored a couple of alternatives in another recent SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78419407/sub-2x2-matrix-product-within-4-dimensional-tensor-along-given-axis  for a (K,N,2,2) array with N-1 sequential multiplications

@hpaulj how would you do it with einsum?

For small N just write something like einsum('...ij,...jk,...kl, X[:,0], X[:,1],etc)of nesteinsumcalls.  Here I think@/matmulwill just as clean and fast.  If you try a complicatedeinsumlook ateinsum_path`.

Just a curiosity, but it should be very easy to procedurally generate the einsum string. Something like einsum_path(make_string(N), *np.rollaxis(x, 1)). This sort of approach may be useful when you're doing some other tensor product instead of matmul.

I think the most concise way to express this would be something like this:
functools.reduce(np.matmul, np.rollaxis(x, 1))

I suspect that's also about as efficient as you can hope for using operations available in numpy.
If it existed, the vectorized API to compute this might look something like this:
np.matmul.reduce(x, axis=1)

but unfortunately reduce is not yet implemented for generalized ufuncs like matmul, and trying this results in
RuntimeError: Reduction not defined on ufunc with signature


This worked for me! Thank you :) Still looking for possibly more efficient solutions but I guess it'll be hard
EDIT: I'm actually using Jax, but I doubt it makes a difference...
