NumPy successive matrix multiplication vectorization
I have a NumPy array ar of shape (M, L, 2, 2). M is usually in the hundreds or thousands, L is usually <= 5.
I want to multiply the L (N, N) matrices successively (multiplied_ar[m] = ar[m, 0, :, :] @ ar[m, 1, :, :] @ ...) to get an array of shape (M, 2, 2). I don't care about the intermediary results, just the final result.
Is it possible to vectorize this somehow so I wouldn't have to iterate over m and l?

What are M, L and N in practice? If N is big and L is small, then a basic matrix multiplication like you did is optimal performance-wise (unless your matrices have some special properties). Also what is the dtype of ar?

Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78445789/12131013

'vectorize' in the numpy context means (usually) using compiled functions/methods to perform the loops faster.  Most of those are 'parallel' in nature, where you don't care what order things are done.  Your case is basically sequential, using the compiled @ at each step.  There are ways of hiding that iteration, but nothing (short of numba) to put it all in C.

@jared The main difference between the two quoted questions, is that here we want all intermediary results (We want ar[m,0,...], then ar[m,0,...]@ar[m,1,...], then ar[m,0,...]@ar[m,1,...]@ar[m,2,...] then ...). Those questions were not asking for that (only for the equivalent of the final ar[m,0,...]@...@ar[m,L-1,...]). One of the questions got an functools.reduce based answer that does give that sure. But what makes a duplicate is when the question is the same, not when the answer is.

@chrslg I understood the question as wanting the same result as my suggested duplicates, not the result you're suggesting OP is asking for.

@jared I understood the word "successively" meaning that. And the reduce in hpaulj's solution seems to indicate the same. But, it seems, at a closer look, that you're right: they also said they wanted a (M,N,N) result, indicating that, indeed, they are interested only in all final ar[m,0,...]@...@ar[m,L-1,...]). In which case, it is indeed a duplicate of said questions.

@JérômeRichard In practice M is in the hundreds or thousands, L usually in the units range, N always = 2. I don't need the intermediary steps. dtype is complex128.

Would've been good to include code that generates test data and a reference solution for checking.

Ok, then the answer of HFZ should be pretty inefficient as well as iterating with @ using a loop indeed. The link in the duplicate flag should be better but I am not sure it is efficient in this case. I would personally use Numba so to write a specific code computing batch 2x2 matrices. At this scale, even just calling a native C function is pretty expensive (actually even a non-unrolled native C loop can be a bit expensive) and Numpy is really not optimized for that. I added a link in the duplicates where there is a Numba solution.

@JérômeRichard Unfortunately I work in a restricted environment where Numba is not currently an option. I will probably try to optimize it using Cython which is used in the codebase. I asked the question to be sure I did not miss some great NumPy function that would solve this case.

@JérômeRichard I linked a benchmark under the answer, how fast would your Numba solution be?

@VaNa Cython would be fine too. You just need to use view to make sure that the array access are native ones and not interpreted. Even if they would be a Numpy function for that, it would not be as efficient as a Cython/Numba/native code because the dimension of the two last axis are too small and Numpy developers do not specialize codes for such use-case (it is not worth it).

@nocomment Online tools are generally not great for profiling. Most are not reliable and even when they are, we do not know or control the environment. Besides, when I press the "Execution" button on this tool, I got no response after 3 min... I am not sure it works on my browser (Firefox). Numba is often competitive with native C code. The two main overheads are generally allocations (not a problem here) and wrap-around. The lack of low-level features can impact the performance of the best implementation but Python rarely use/need that anyway. Cython can be equally fast to C in most cases

@JérômeRichard ATO (that online tool) is pretty good, I do lots of benchmarking there. Usually more sophisticated/stable than this time, but "several times faster" was all I needed here. Maybe you were unlucky, sometimes the runner is down. Anyway, I didn't mean to add your Numba solution there (I don't think it supports that), I just thought you could get the code there so you don't have to write it yourself, and could run it wherever you like with your Numba solution added, if you were willing to do that.

you could use python's functools.reduce(func,seq) along with np.einsum:
import functools
a=np.random.rand(M,L,N,N)
b = np.transpose(a, (1, 0, 2, 3))
def m_einsum(A1, A2):
  return np.einsum('fij,fjk->fik', A1, A2)

res=functools.reduce(m_einsum, b)


Simple loop seems ~5 times faster
